# Json file with bash

Tags: bash, json

I need delete space and value kubernetes from json file with use bash script:

Content json file

Input

```
 "spec": {
        "finalizers": [
            "kubernetes"
        ]
    },
```

Ouput

```
 "spec": {
        "finalizers": []
    },
```

Comment: It's generally recommended to use a JSON parsing tool for JSON data. Can you use [tag:jq]?

Answer (score 1):

Given "input.json"

```json
{
  "spec": {
          "finalizers": [
              "kubernetes"
          ]
      },
  "other": 42
  }
```

Then

```sh
jq '.spec.finalizers = []' input.json
```

outputs

```json
{
  "spec": {
    "finalizers": []
  },
  "other": 42
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gleen! It worked

Answer (score 0):

Lets use some `sed` magic with regex:

```
echo 'Input "spec": { "finalizers": [ "kubernetes" ] },' | sed -r 's/Input (.* \[) \".*\" (\].*)/\1\2/'
```

Which returns:

```
"spec": { "finalizers": [] },
```

`sed` -r uses extended regex (-E on osx), and "()" are used for capture groups, which is what the \1 and \2 refers to, so first we capture everything up to "[", then match everything from the "]" until the end.

The downside of this is that your input doesn't look like complete json, so modifying the regex to match the proper input can be much harder.

I would also recommend you to look at `jq`, the defacto tool for json parsing in CLI.

Comment: Thank Fredrik for you help.